# How can I change the apache solr search URL in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, solr

How can I change the default apache solr URL path `search/apachesolr_search/term` to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a menu item that has the callback:

$menu['search']['page callback'] = 'apachesolr_search_view';

This will make that url use the apachesolr search as it's return.

What are you trying to change it to?